# Calling 9-1-1 with Siri

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

If I try to call 9-1-1 using Siri, she says "Calling 9-1-1. I'm sorry, I can't call 9-1-1."

Is there really no way to call 9-1-1 from a hands-free position? This is such a strange issue; I can't imagine a single advantage to intentionally disabling this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Calling emergency numbers is prohibited in Siri to prevent accidental calls being made. You need to use the Phone app manually or the Emergency dialer on the lock screen to make calls to emergency numbers.

However, in some locations, you can say something similar to 'call the police' and this will succeed as I believe Siri is more accurately able to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Has anybody tried making a contact named 911 that then dials '911' when asked thru' Siri?